# How to show/hide div with javascript?

Tags: javascript

So I want to hide a div for user settings, which shows when the user clicks on a little cog icon. What is the best way for me to go about this?

I made a couple of very basic pics to show what I'm after:

Closed:

[image]

Open:

[image]

Once the user clicks the icon (the red dot) then I want the hidden div to push the content to its right over. I had a look at the CSS checkbox hack, but that requires the user to click directly on the icon (the red dot) again to close the hidden div. I would like to have it so the user can click anywhere else on the page to close the div.

Anyone know how to do this with pure js?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: how far did you get with this?

Comment: Where is your HTML/CSS and JS?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `tabindex="-1"` in order to use `:focus`.

This way you can achieve it with pure CSS.

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;  right: 0;  bottom: 0;  left: 0;
}
#sidebar, #main, #hidden:focus {
  padding: 10px;
}
#sidebar {
  background: #A8D4AF;
}
#main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: #96A7B1;
}
#hidden {
  width: 0;
  background: #008DD2;
}
#hidden:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  left: -40px;  top: 40px;    /* Position of the dot*/
  width: 20px;  height: 20px; /* Size of the dot */
  margin-bottom: -20px;       /* Same as height */
}
#hidden:focus:before {
  display: none;
}
#hidden:focus {
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="sidebar">
    Test content
  </div>
  <div id="hidden" tabindex="-1">
    Hidden stuff
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    Lorem ipsum dolor
  </div>
</div>
```